# How to create an html page or templateUrl out of multiple html templates

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and I already have a simple webapp running locally on my computer. I have the following code in the `main.js` app file:

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', ['ngRoute']); 
webApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) 
        {
            $routeProvider. 
            when('/', {
                    templateUrl : '/app/pages/home.phtml',
                    controller  : 'mainController'
            }).
            when('/signin', {
                    templateUrl : '/app/pages/signin.phtml',
                    controller  : 'signinController'
            }).
            when('/forgot', {
                    templateUrl : 'app/pages/forgot.phtml',
                    controller  : 'forgotController'
            }).
            when('/signup', {
                    templateUrl : 'app/pages/home.phtml',
                    controller  : 'signupController'
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

I was wondering what is the proper approach in angularjs for this specific case:
Let's say I want to create the `home.phtml` out of multiple html files (or html elements that are stored in files), in other words I want to break up the html page into multiple html files (templates) so that I can merge/combine each element separately whenever it is necessary.

- How can I do this in angularjs?
- Is it a good practice to create an html page this way(performance)?
- How can I cache the elements?
- Is it going to be dynamic or static? if so how can I create a templateUrl dynamically and use it?
  I have read some articles but I can't really wrap my mind around the problem because I don't have global knowledge of angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-include from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

as an element:

```
<ng-include
  src="string"
  [onload="string"]
  [autoscroll="string"]>
  ...
</ng-include>
```

or inside any other element:

```
<ANY
  ng-include="string"
  [onload="string"]
  [autoscroll="string"]>
  ...
</ANY>
```

or as a class:

```
<ANY class="ng-include: string; [onload: string;] [autoscroll: string;]"> ... </ANY>
```

basically, inside your html file where you want to include the other template just add in a `<ng-include src="yourtemplate.html"></ng-include>`